# Should the [vlsi] tag be added to the list of synonyms for the [integrated-circuit] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The [info page for the vlsi tag](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/vlsi/info) states:

> it is used as a generic term to mean ICs in common usage.

and it is similar to the [integrated-circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/integrated-circuit/info) tag info.

Also, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_Large_Scale_Integration) states:

> Very large-scale integration (VLSI) is the process of creating an
> integrated circuit (IC)

The term "VLSI" is a bit generic, and when the tag is added to questions, it typically refers to ICs.

I tried to suggest this as a [synonym](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/integrated-circuit/synonyms), but I do not meet the criteria to do so.

Answer (score 6):

> What are tag synonyms?
>
> Tag synonyms allow us to fix incorrect tags by substituting them with
> the correct tags. When should I propose a tag synonym?
>
> Whenever you see questions being repeatedly tagged with the wrong or
> incorrect tag -- or multiple tags that mean the same thing -- it's a
> good idea to propose a tag synonym. The goal is to avoid manually
> editing the tags on every post by making the retagging automatic for
> common tag mistakes.

[enter link description here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

It would probably not be a good idea to rename the VSLI tag to integrated circuit tag.

Creating a synonym would essentially retag all the VSLI questions to integrated circuit, VSLI questions usually describe the engineering and design of such chips and tag information would be lost if somebody was specifically searching for the VSLI

I would probably be better to edit the tag description to reflect a better definition

Comment: I think that the terms IC and VLSI are rather different in common use. So +1 for adjusting the tag descriptions.